# Having trouble with SignInAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am having trouble implementing an existing database with user credentials into a new MVC5 application. This is the error I got when running the code, and attemtping to log in with the credentials from the existing database. I've never customized authentication on an MVC project, i've only used the Controllers that come along with the MVC project.
This is the error I am getting.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

If I type in wrong credentials I do get the "Invalid username/password" error, so it knows that the database is there. But when I input the correct credentials it throws this error out. Any idea as to what it would be?

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
```

Also this is the method that the source error is pointing to.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

Comment: Have you disabled role and membership in your web config?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your answer, but for me, this was the issue in the past...  If you are using SQL Azure then you will have to configure the remote server for access via your IP address.

To make sure your IP is allowed to access the database, go to Azure -> select your database -> Dashboard -> allowed ip addresses -> then add your IP to the list.

Comment: I am not using SQL Azure.

Comment: @Brian Fair enough, I will keep this answer here in case someone else finds it and is using SQL Azure.

Comment: Yea that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Does the SQL user account have read / write access to the schema (guessing dbo if auth tables are default)?

Comment: It does, it has admin level access.